# Unable to get login page with wget command

Tags: html, linux, wget

I want to create the exact same page as this page using the wget command on the local host, but only the black background is displayed and I cannot get the username and password forms. Please tell me the solution. Thank you very much.

This is the command I entered.

```
wget -pkK https://www.epicgames.com/id/login
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why?**

the login page is rendered by javascript, so you can't get the rendered html.

**How to get the html you want?**

You can copy the html in the developer inspect tool in a browser (which can execute javascript). see the follow image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whgRa.png)